# Do I need to download each x.d.ts file to my app?

Tags: typescript

In order to have type checking when I use fs.readFile in TS I need to add:

```
/// <reference path="node.d.ts" />
```

to my ts file, correct? Therefore is the 'best practice' to download the most recent version of the file node.d.ts to my own app's code and then manually make sure I have the most recent one?

Or is there a better, more automated way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to download a definition file that **maches** your installed node version.
Also you can use [tsd](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/) to manage your typescript definitions.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to add: `/// <reference path="node.d.ts" />` to my ts file, correct?

No. You just need to have `node.d.ts` *in your project* so that it becomes a part of your compilation context. Look at using `tsconfig.json` for this : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md

> to download the most recent version of the file node.d.ts to my own app's code and then manually make sure I have the most recent one

Use tsd as mentioned by alisabzevari